# remove href functionality from category in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, category, category-tree

I have category and sub category in top menu, i want href functionality to be disabled for category, so when i click on category it should not do any thing.
Just like we have in backend magento admin panel, second tab sales, nothing happens on clicking on sales, on hover it shows subcategories.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty method. Add this javascript code to the footer

```
$$('a.level-top').each(function(elem){
    $(elem).href='#';
});
```

Slow and clean method:
You need to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::_addCategoriesToMenu` and change this:

```
$categoryData = array(
    'name' => $category->getName(),
    'id' => $nodeId,
    'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
    'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category)
);
```

to this:

```
$categoryData = array(
    'name' => $category->getName(),
    'id' => $nodeId,
    'url' => (($category->getLevel() == 2) ? '#' : Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category)),
    'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category)
);
```

Comment: thanks dirty way works with one problem sometimes it shows href='#' and on page refresh some time its href changes to home page href="domain.com".

Comment: huh? how is that possible? Do you have any other javascript that manipulates the href of the menu items?

Comment: no there is nothing else, links are active while page is loading because javascript is in footer i have to wait until full page is loaded and script is executed. I will try other way thanks